# How do I dynamically add vertices to a graph?

Tags: c++, graph-theory

I'm doing some work on data structures, just to learn. Right now I have an admittedly very basic graph data structure.

I can create the graph with a predefined size, and then add edges to/from each vertex (un-directed). Here is the code so far:

**graph.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Graph {
    int vertices; // num of vertices in graph
    std::vector<int> *adjList;
public:
    Graph(int vertices);
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    void printGraph();
};

Graph::Graph(int vertices) {
    this->vertices = vertices;
    adjList = new std::vector<int>[vertices];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) {
    adjList[v].push_back(w);
}

void  Graph::printGraph() {
    for (int i = 0; i < adjList->size(); ++i) {

    }

}
```

**graph.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "graph.h"

int main()
{
    Graph graph(4);
    graph.addEdge(0, 1); //counter starts at 0
    graph.addEdge(0, 2);
    graph.addEdge(2, 1);
    graph.addEdge(2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

This works fairly well, however I would also like to add nodes after the graph object has already been created. I really can't figure out how to do this.

Any sort of guidance towards this (as well as general improvements to the code) will  be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A dynamically allocated array of `std::vector`s? That's a new one. Because of that, to add a vertex you would need to reallocate a larger array, copy the elements over and then delete the original array.

Comment: You almost never want to dynamically allocate a `vector`. `vector`'s main job is to hide dynamic allocation from you and do all the work involved so you don't have to. Dynamically allocating a `vector` undoes part of that noble effort. Side note: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: What makes you think you need to dynamically allocate the vector? There's such thing as a vector of vectors, or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vector to store your adjacency list and resize it when required:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adjList;
```

Don't allocate it with `new`, don't delete it, use standard containers!

Comment: There's a bit more subtlety to it than that. `addEdge(100002, 3);` has to make sure  there is a 100002. Be it a few thousand `push_back`s or a `resize`.

Comment: Of course, OP needs to do this check when doing `addEdge`.

Comment: I agree on this as well. Depends on what OP wants to do with the edges numbering.